# Why does carriage return in excel is not reflected when excel value is imported in UFT

Tags: excel, hp-uft, carriage-return

I am using Excel to compare error messages. My error message looks like this .

```
You have changed the values.
Do you want to continue?
```

I entered this value in excel using Alt+Enter, when reading this value from UFT, this carriage return is not considered.

How to include carriage return in excel so that it is visible when reading the values from UFT?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to create a string formula, i.e. instead of entering the line break in the string, create a formular like

> ="<value>"

where <value> is the string value that you originally wanted in your cell, with the line feed contained within the quotation marks.

This might solve your issue.

But:

**This is just the top of the mountain of known issues with UFTs data table API.** Here is an incomplete list of additional issues (some of which, but not all, are fixed or at least improved upon in 15+):

- Date values are not properly handled, especially if you are using a
  non-US locale and try to consume values auto-formatted by Excel as
  dates
- Strange things happen if you have an .xls file. Use an .xlsx file instead. (This used to be the other way around). Note it is not only the extension I am referring to, but also the format (Excel-95 vs. more modern format)
- Many formulas are unsupported Formatting behavior differentfrom what Excel would do/show
- CRs and LFs are handled differently
  from what Excel does
- Built-in table editor is quite a silo of bugs
  and antiergonomic cell values are limited in length; at the same
  time, formulas have different length limits. I.e. a string in a cell is
  limited to a certain maximum number of characters, but a formular
  returning a string does not have that (but maybe a higher) length
  limit

Because of this (and more), we auto-convert all excel sheets on the fly before when we use them in UFT after they have been updated. To do this, we are using Excel Interop (i.e. Excel´s COM automation interface) to spawn an Excel instance, create a converted version that has all formulas and formatting resolved to just string formulars, and use the converted sheets with UFTs DataTable.ImportSheet feature. Which means we unfortunately need Excel on all execution machines.

**So my recommendation would be to stay away from the data table editor in UFT. Use Excel, and make sure all your edits come through to UFT in a meaningful way.** If they don´t, consider a converter that creates a DataTable-compatible copy of your sheet.

Yes, I know this is suboptimal, but that´s what it has come down to after years and years of struggling with the DataTable API and UFTs "superb" built-in data table editor.